# image quality not reducing after selecting image from react-native-image-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am using `react-native-image-picker` to select images from gallery, but `react-native-image-picker` not reducing image quality after selecting an image. Both original and compressed images size are the same. How to reduce image quality by using `react-native-image-picker`?

```
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';

const chooseFile = () => {
        let options = {
            mediaType: 'photo',
            quality: 0.5,
        };
        launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
const chooseFile = () => {
    let options = {
        mediaType: 'photo',
        maxHeight: 1000, //any number lesser will resize the image to a lower quality
    };
    launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);
    });
};
```

use the maxHeight or maxWidth to resize the image to lower quality image

Comment: what is the use of quality? It should reduce the size of the image.

Comment: There is no information about the quality prop in the library apart from listing